# which is the best among jquery,moo tool and yui?

Tags: javascript, cross-browser, javascript-framework

Hi among the jquery ,mootool ,yui and glow have crossbrowser compatiblity

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why is jQuery so widely adopted versus other Javascript frameworks?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/990077/why-is-jquery-so-widely-adopted-versus-other-javascript-frameworks)

Comment: You're going to find jQuery to be the most *popular* here at StackOverflow. Embarrassingly, this site is the worst sampling pool you could use to determine the *best* framework (which completely depends on your requirements, anyway).

Answer (score 1):

jquery - all the way! I avoid the rest of the tools!

Comment: That's ignorant. There are no silver bullets in the software industry.  It's one thing to "not know" MooTools, Prototype, etc .. but to completely avoid them is idiotic and can potentially limit your contract opportunities.

Comment: Didn’t mean to upset you, sounds like I touched a nerve?

It’s not that ignorant, in my opinion and a lot of the other professionals out there rate jquery over the other tools. 

So rather than dabbling with them all, I’d prefer be a master of one. jquery is my preference. Maybe I could have worded it better, I’ll try again  –

At this moment in time all I use is jquery as there are lot of tools and help / support out there, I’ve never had the need to look into any of the other tools, or what I have they don’t appear to be as good as jquery – I hope that doesn’t sound ignorant...

Answer (score 0):

By best you have to define what you mean. It depends on many factors.

I prefer jquery since its user base is too large and the availability of plugins.

Answer (score 0):

JQuery has been gaining good popularity. The compatibilty of JQuery with most of the browsers is higher. Jquery has picked up very well and so, Its better to try out JQuery only.

Answer (score 0):

I use jQuery, becouse it's intuitive and there is a lot of feedback and plugins.

compatibility
Jquery: Firefox 2.0+
Internet Explorer 6+
Safari 3+
Opera 9+
Chrome 1+, There are known problems with: Firefox 1.0.x
Internet Explorer 1.0-5.x
Safari 1.0-2.0.1
Opera 1.0-8.x
Konqueror

Mootool: MooTools is compatible and fully tested with Safari 2+, Internet Explorer 6+, Firefox 2+ (and browsers based on gecko), Opera 9+, and Chrome 4+.

Yui: http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/articles/gbs/

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend **jQuery** above anything. Microsoft visual studio 2010 ships with jQuery support which is a good benchmark for this test. Also jQuery has vast audience that develop plugins for jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

[Here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_JavaScript_frameworks) you can see comparison of javascript frameworks. Personally I vote for jQuery, because at its slogan says ***Write less, do more.***

Update
Right here, in stackoverflow you can see the hot discussion about this subject in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/394601/which-javascript-framework-jquery-vs-dojo-vs).

Answer (score 0):

At the end of the day, it depends what you want to use the framework *for*.

I would recommend that you start by learning to write pure javascript, only then will you find out where the relative utility of a framework comes in.

If you want a framework that has the widest browser compatibility, along with best performance on older computers/browsers then the rather annoyingly named 'my library' probably wins out. 
Simply because it does feature detection rather than try to infer the browser name / version, which is a rather craptastic cop-out that most of the established libraries are guilty of.

I would recommend you give each of them a go and see what suits your need, locking yourself in to one particular framework too early will only hurt you long term; When holding a hammer, every screw looks like a nail etc.

Personally I favor YUI3 - it has strong OOP support as well as flexible CSS3 style DOM querying and a great selection of quality RIA widgets.

I wouldn't let myself be too swayed by arguments ad populem, plenty of people do silly things, find out what is right for you and your problem domain.